# How do I make sure my Xcode UITest Target Only Builds the Target Application?

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I have an Swift iOS project with 50+ targets each of which makes a slightly different version of the app for different clients (Different App Icons / Logos / Names / Colours etc).

I also have a test target for UI Testing with XCTest. The problem is that when I run a test rather than just building the target that has been selected as the Target Application for the test it is building all 50+ targets.

Obviously this takes  a VERY long and will only get longer as more targets are added so I need to work out how to make sure that the only target that gets built is the target application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I figured it out so will put the answer here in case anyone else has the same problem.

Basically, In the Test Target -> Build Phases -> Target Dependencies all the targets had been added as dependencies unnecessarily. I just needed to remove them all.